# Setting different GDAL configuration folder when calling ogr2ogr with Python subprocess

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, subprocess

I'm trying to access a web resource through the Python subprocess module and ogr2ogr/ogrinfo.
When calling ogr through the command line, everything works fine.
When calling with subprocess I have an error. I finally discovered that ogr calls the configuration files from the ArcGIS Pro folder (I'm using conda environment that I cloned from ArcPy) even though I specify using ogrinfo that is installed in the OSGeo4W folder.

Anyway to override this (temporarily, just before the call and then reset it afterwards) ?
I guess I have to set [GDAL_CONFIG_FILE](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html) but I'm not sure how exactly to do this?

On Windows 10.

Command line: `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogrinfo -ro -al -so --debug ON "https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson"` gives:

```
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MG4Lidar.dll using GDALRegister_MG4Lidar.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll using GDALRegister_MrSID.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll using RegisterOGROCI.
GDAL: Auto register C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll using RegisterOGRSOSI.
HTTP: Fetch(https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson)
HTTP: libcurl/7.75.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1o zlib/1.2.12 WinIDN
...
```

Calling with subprocess

```py
ogrinfoPath = os.path.join("C:"+os.sep, "OSGeo4W", "bin", "ogrinfo.exe") 
args = [ogrinfoPath, "-ro", "-al", "-so", "--debug", "ON", "https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson"]
cmd = subprocess.run(args)
```

gives:

```
CPL: Loading configuration from C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalrc
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW.  
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_GRIB.dll using GDALRegister_GRIB.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF4.dll using GDALRegister_HDF4.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_JP2KAK.dll using GDALRegister_JP2KAK.  
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_JPEGLS.dll using GDALRegister_JPEGLS.  
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_JPIPKAK.dll using GDALRegister_JPIPKAK.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_KEA.dll using GDALRegister_KEA.        
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll using GDALRegister_MrSID.    
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_netCDF.dll using GDALRegister_netCDF.  
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_NITF.dll using GDALRegister_NITF.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_PDF.dll using GDALRegister_PDF.
HTTP: Fetch(https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson)
HTTP: libcurl/7.75.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1o zlib/1.2.12 WinIDN
Warning 6: HTTP/2 not available in this build of Curl. It needs to be built against nghttp2
Warning 6: GDAL_HTTP_USE_CAPI_STORE requested, but libcurl too old, non-Windows platform or OpenSSL missing.    
HTTP: These HTTP headers were set: Accept: text/plain, application/json
HTTP: Fetch(https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson)
Warning 6: GDAL_HTTP_USE_CAPI_STORE requested, but libcurl too old, non-Windows platform or OpenSSL missing.
HTTP: These HTTP headers were set: Accept: text/plain, application/json
HTTP: Fetch(https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson)
Warning 6: GDAL_HTTP_USE_CAPI_STORE requested, but libcurl too old, non-Windows platform or OpenSSL missing.
HTTP: These HTTP headers were set: Accept: text/plain, application/json
CouchDB: GET /_all_dbs
HTTP: Establish persistent session named 'CouchDB:0000021D12671860'.
HTTP: Fetch(https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson/_all_dbs)
HTTP: These POSTFIELDS were sent:
HTTP: These HTTP headers were set: Content-Type: application/json
HTTP: Ended persistent session named 'CouchDB:0000021D12671860'.
HTTP: Fetch(https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson)
Warning 6: GDAL_HTTP_USE_CAPI_STORE requested, but libcurl too old, non-Windows platform or OpenSSL missing.    
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `https://data.montreal.ca/dataset/b628f1da-9dc3-4bb1-9875-1470f891afb1/resource/92cb062a-11be-4222-9ea5-867e7e64c5ff/download/limites-terrestres.geojson' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRIC
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> PDS4
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the `GDAL_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable for only that process you can pass the `env` arg to [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

This expects a dict containing the complete set of vars to be used, so you should pass the entire contents of `os.environ` with the relevant vars added/modified.  Something like this:

```py
import os
import subprocess

env = os.environ.copy()
env['GDAL_CONFIG_FILE'] = r'C:\example\gdalrc'

subprocess.run(['gdalinfo', '--version'], env=env)
```

Comment: So there isn't a gdalrc (GDAL_CONFIG_FILE) in my OSGeo4W installation, just passed an empty string: `env['GDAL_CONFIG_FILE'] = ""` in the `os.environ.copy()` and it works!


I also noticed that the `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` points to the ArcGIS folder as well, but didn't need to change it (this time!).